# Python subprocess.Popen for multiple python scripts

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to understand the Popen method. I currently have three python files in the same directory: test.py, hello.py and bye.py. test.py is the file containing the subprocess.Popen method while hello and bye are simple hello world and goodbye world files i.e. they only contain a single print.

if I do:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE

tst = subprocess.Popen(["python", "hello.py"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
(out,err) = tst.communicate()
```

Everything seems to work fine, obtaining in the shell the proper "Hello World" print for the hello.py and doing the same for bye.py the shell prints "GoodBye World" as it should.

The issue starts when I want to run both files,

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE

tst = subprocess.Popen(["python", "hello.py", "python", "bye.py"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
(out,err) = tst.communicate()
```

This will only return the print for the first .py file, and then return

```
[WinError 2 ] The system cannot find the file specified
```

This will happen if I also remove the second "python". Why is this happening?

Comment: If you know one works why not split it into two consecutive calls?

Comment: You can try to add a semicolon before the 2nd `"python"` if you really want to call both in one call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This will happen if I also remove the second "python". Why is this happening?

Running

```
subprocess.Popen(["python", "hello.py", "python", "bye.py"]
```

is akin to running

```
$ python hello.py python bye.py
```

which doesn't really make a whole lot of sense, since that's interpreted as passing the arguments `hello.py python bye.py` to `python`.

So that's part 1, to your question "I am trying to understand the Popen method."

Without knowing what you actually want to *do* with this proof of concept, you have a few options; call multiple `Popen()` sequentially, or use a semicolon with `shell=True`, but make sure to consider the [security implications](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) of that:

```
# This will also break on Windows
>>> import subprocess as sp
>>> sp.check_output("python -V ; python -V", shell=True)
b'Python 3.8.2\nPython 3.8.2\n'
```